# Adding custom headers to Azure Functions response

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working on an Azure Function App (v2), which has a number of different functions inside the same Function App.

It is going to be deployed in multiple Azure regions, and I would like to add a custom header, that indicates which region served the request.

I know that I can let each function return `HttpResponseMessage` which can contain custom headers. Instead of duplicating that code to each function, I would like to make it centralized in the entire Function App project. Another drawback of returning `HttpResponseMessage` is that I would like to use `IActionResult`, so I can use `JsonResult` or `OkObjectResult` and similar return types.

With an ASP.NET MVC project, I could add a middleware which added the header or add the headers using `web.config`. Neither seems to be possible in a Function App.

How can this be done without having to return `HttpResponseMessage` and adding the header inside each function's `Run` method?

Comment: Hve a look at function filter, it should fit your requirements: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. Function filters are close to what I want. At least they are injected into the Function's execution flow. But it seems the feature isn't done yet (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1284) and they can't modify the function's response (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1314)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now possible to inject middleware that can add custom headers to functions responses.

**Registration**

```cs
public static void Main()
{
  var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(workerApplication =>
    {
      workerApplication.UseWhen<StampHttpHeaderMiddleware>((context) =>
      {
        // We want to use this middleware only for http trigger invocations.
        return context.FunctionDefinition.
          InputBindings.Values.First(
            a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type == "httpTrigger";
      });
    })
   .Build();
  host.Run();
```

**Implementation**

```cs
internal sealed class StampHttpHeaderMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
      context.GetHttpResponseData()?.Headers.Add("x-myCustomHeader", "custom header value");
    }
}
```

(code is adapted from the [GitHub sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples/CustomMiddleware))

Comment: This is only for isolated right, not in-process function apps?

Answer (score 43):

I was able to do this by accessing the `HttpResponse` object via the request's `HttpContext`.

For example:

```
req.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("ETag", entity.ETag);
return new OkObjectResult(entity);
```

produces:
[image]

Comment: I tried sublcassing `OkObjectResult` but I can't set the header from in there.  Was really hoping to make it cleaner.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @BillNoel custom headers need to be set on the `Response` not the result. The result is only concerned with the return value, status code and content type (which I believe will affect the *Content-Type* header for the response), but to set a custom header you need to use the `HttpResponse`.

Comment: where I can find response headers in HttpRequestMessage object?

Answer (score 3):

while researching the exact same problem, I came along [this blog post](https://medium.com/@steinardahl/how-to-set-custom-http-response-headers-from-c-azure-functions-50ffd04e337e).
Basically, you derive a custom class fomr JsonResult, OKResult and so on and manipulate the `ExecuteResultAsync` method and add your headers there.

```cs
public class ServiceUnavailableResult : StatusCodeResult {
    private readonly int _retryAfterHeaderValue;

    public ServiceUnavailableResult(int retryAfterHeaderValue) : base(500) {
        _retryAfterHeaderValue = retryAfterHeaderValue;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context) {
        await base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
        
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Retry-After", _retryAfterHeaderValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

It does not fully help you, but if you only use like two or three classes when returning content, it might.

Comment: This didn't quite work for us but overriding the `ExecuteResultAsync` method did.